# SPOJ Sum of Digits

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve the problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/CPCRC1C/ using the approach 
discussed in
http://goo.gl/YzEwXR

This is my implementation of the above algorithm

```
void solve(int i, bool lo, bool hi, char *A, char *B, int n, unsigned long long &sum,int numSum) {

if (i == n) {
    sum+=numSum;
    return;
}

char d = hi ? '0' : A[i];
char end = lo ? '9' : B[i];
for (; d <= end; d++) {

    int nnumSum=numSum ;
    nnumSum += (d-48);
   // cout<<"\nd="<<d<<"  sum="<<nnumSum;
    solve(i + 1, lo || d < B[i], hi || d > A[i], A, B, n, sum,nnumSum);
}
}
```

Can you suggest me how I can optimize the algo using memoization?

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Do you think all readers will follow your link to understand your question? Better give a minimal code and ask the specific question.

Comment: With a TLE you are either not yet acting `3rd-grade` or `quite well`.

Answer (score 0):

CPCRC1C

```
1) sum of digits from 1 to b, let this count be sum(b)

2) sum of digits from 1 to a-1, let this count be sum(a-1)
```

Return difference between two counts

How to compute sum(x)?
Let us try finding out a pattern

What is sum(9)?

```
1 2 3 4 ........... 9
9*10/2 = 45
```

What is sum(19)?
sum(9) + sum of digits in following numbers

```
10 11 12 13 ....... 19
10 + 9*10/2 = 10 + 45 [10 is sum of first digit in all numbers]
```

What is sum(29)?
sum(19) + sum of digits in following numbers

```
20 21 22 23 ........29
20 + 9*10/2 = 20 + 45
```

What is sum(100)?

```
45 + (10 + 45) + (20 + 45) + (30 + 45) + ..... (90 + 45)
45*10 + (10 + 20 + 30 ... 90)
45*10 + 10(1 + 2 + ... 9)
45*10 + 45*10
45*20
```

We can use above pattern to come up with a formula that can directly compute sum

source : [GeeksforGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-sum-of-digits-in-numbers-from-1-to-n/)